# How to make Gears mesh

Tags: javascript, math, physics, game-physics

(I don't know a lot of gear type terminology...)

I have two gears (Gear A and B) that I'm trying to get to mesh.

**Things That Work**
I've successfully written code that makes sure the gears are the correct distance apart and that rotates gears with varying numbers of cogs at the appropriate speed based on this number.

**The Problem**
I am having trouble calculating at what rotation gear B should be when it's placed next to Gear A so that the cogs on the gears mesh together (the cog size is the same on both gears).

Gear A is centered at x1,y1 and is rotated at *q* degrees.  Gear B is centered at x2,y2 and is *d* distance from Gear A.  The distance between two cogs on a gear is *c*.

I use `Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1) *(180/Math.PI);` to calculate the angle between the two gears relative to the origin but don't always get good results (may be an issue in my code somewhere else, not sure...)  My thought was to use this angle and *q* to compute a rotational value for gear B.

I could probably use `q%c` to get a more precise/smaller rotation value for gear B, but not sure quite how to proceed.

Comment: have no idea... have you tried on SO's sister sites that directly address math of this kind?

Comment: Note that if your gears are regular all the way around you really only have to manage a small range of angles--just concern yourself with the closest tooth on each gear. If they are full meshing gears as well then the problem reduces to getting the center of the teeth on one wheel to point to the center of the gaps on the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a gear with n cogs. If n is even, then opposite every cog is another cog. If n is odd then opposite every cog is a notch (or whatever the correct term is). In either case, if you rotate the gear by 2π/n radians, it will look the same as it did before-- each cog has "moved over". So angle matters only modulo 2π/n.

Consider two identical gears, meshing, both centered on the x-axis (y=0). If n is odd, then their angle can be equal (we can call that angle 0, when a cog is pointing in the **x** direction), and in general if one gear is at angle **a**, then the other will be at angle **-a**. If n is even then when one gear is at 0, the other will be at π/n, and in general when one is at **a** the other will be at **π/n-a**.

Now suppose that the gear on the left ("gear A") has n cogs and the gear on the right ("gear B") has m cogs. If m is odd then when gear B is at **am**, gear A is at **-an**. If m is even, when gear B is at **am**, gear A is at **π/n-an**.

Now suppose that their centers are not at the same y value, so that the center of gear B is at angle **b** as seen from the center of gear A. Now the subtract that angle from the angle of rotation of each gear, and you reduce the problem to the previous one.

Comment: This is sounding really good.  I'll try it when I get home tonight and post my code if/when I get it working.

Comment: To make things easier, all of my gears have an odd number of cogs.  I tried creating a formula that I could plug some numbers into but I may have misunderstood part of your explanation.  I started off simple and just set var br = -asRotation;  This worked as expected and regardless of the current rotation of gear A the new rotation for gear B was always correct when at x=0.  I ran into issues trying to create the final formula though.  What I came up with was var newBAngle = (asRotation-theta)*cogCount; but it doesn't mesh right.  Suggestions?

Comment: 1) You're skipping a step, 2) look what happens when theta=0, you get nonsense. The second step should be br = -asRotation*aCogs/bCogs. Try that, work out the bugs before you try the last step.

Comment: I've taken some time to think it over (no guarantees...) but I think I've almost got it.  I say almost because it works 90+% of the time and works for 0/90/180/270 degree angles all the time.  The equation I have right now is var br = (-ar-theta)*(aCogs/bcogs)-theta;  Any ideas on whats not quite right?  It works so much of the time now that I am really hopeful.

Comment: I tried that one first since you said subtract from both gears but it doesn't come up with the right values.

Comment: While making some examples I discovered that the result of my angle calculation was inverted.  I multiplied it by -1 and and from then on everything worked great.  Thanks for all your help.